# How to schedule ECS tasks in fan out architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-ecs

I have a video which I want to upload to S3. After uploading the video I want to run three ECS tasks `A,B,C` (each tasks get the same `video_id`). Those ECS tasks upload many rows to Dynamodb tables (ECS task `A` uploads to Table `A`, `B` to `B`, `C` to `C`). Each row in the tables contains the `video_id`.

After tasks `A,B,C` finish, I want that task `Z` would run (task `Z` takes data from Tables `A,B,C`).

How do I trigger those three ECS tasks after uploading file to S3 in the simplest way, and how to trigger ECS task `Z` after `A,B,C` finishing uploading rows for video to tables `A,B,C`?

P.S.I prefer event driven solution.

[image]

Comment: I think you're looking for a [workflow engine](https://github.com/meirwah/awesome-workflow-engines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an AWS Step Function that has a [parallel state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html), with three branches, with one state each, that invoke the ECS tasks A,B and C respectively.

Configure a final state in the step function to run task Z, and configure this state to depend on the previous parallel state.

Then, use [S3 event notification to invoke the Step Function on S3 object uploads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html).